# Node.js mysql in function returns undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here's my code

```
function getprefix(guildid) {
    con.connect(function(err) {
        con.query('SELECT * from ' + configcontent.guilds_table_name + ' WHERE guild_id=' + String(guildid), function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                return result[0].prefix;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I wanted to make this function to return one value from one column (from first result), but it returns undefined. When i tried to write it on screen (using `console.log(result[0].prefix);`) it works.
Please help. Sorry for bad description or english. Its my first question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

Your function is asynchronous, so it immediately returns result, now it returns undefined. Value from DB returned later, and passed to callback. You need to use promises(preferred)/callbacks to return async results from your function, something like this:

```
function getprefix(guildid) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.connect(function (err) {
          con.query('SELECT * from ' + configcontent.guilds_table_name + ' WHERE guild_id=' + String(guildid), function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              // throw err;
              // instead of throwing we passing error to result promise
              reject(err)
            } else {
              // return result[0].prefix;
              // instead of return we pass result to promise
              resolve(result[0].prefix)
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

so usage will look like:

```
getprefix(guildid)
  .then(prefix => console.log(prefix))
  .catch(e => console.err('Unable to get prefix', e))
```

it would be great to check the different ways to handle async programming in JS with *callbacks/promises/async awaits* in details.

Comment: But the question is how to use promise to assign value to variable? Should i replace console.log(prefix) with this or what else?

Comment: @Mruczacy could you show us how you use `getprefix` in your applicatio? i see you dont know exactly how promises work in JS

Answer (score 0):

You can't return value from a callback.

Before you make your query, connect to the db. Don't use the callback function for that, cuz making a query supposed to be made with `con.query`

```
function getprefix(guildid) {
    con.connect();
    con.query('SELECT * from ' + configcontent.guilds_table_name + ' WHERE guild_id=' + String(guildid), function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
           throw err;
        } else {
           // do stuff with 'results'
        }
    });
```

### EDIT

You can use `async/await` like this to get access to the return value, but you have to wrap your code in an **IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)** or use top level `await`, but it's only available in the latest version of Node.

Note, that I only used IIFE, because I don't have any other function or logic where I could call my query. If you call it in another function, make it `async`.

```
// Top level action
(async () => {
  const output = await makeQuery();
  console.log(output);
})();

// Query
function makeQuery() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    db.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, res) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(res);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried your way in returning value but it doesn't works. It still returns undefined

Comment: Why do you think it won't work? I tested it and it works perfectly.

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized what you were refering to. :D I'm gonna remove that part